# Odoo Field Access 3 Dots? Accessing a field of a field? This does not make sense

Tags: python, orm, odoo, odoo-11

I am confused by this syntax in the Python wrapper to the *Odoo* Object-Relational Mapping (ORM). I understand this is one way to access a field: `table_name.field_name`. However, I am not sure what this means `table_name.field_name.field_name`. I am not sure I am reading this correctly. This may not mean what I think the code means.

We are using the Odoo 11 API. The documentation for this topic, "field access", can be seen at the following URL: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/orm.html#field-access

They even give an example but do not give a detailed explanation or a table definition of the relational database table they are referencing via Python.

```
>>> record.name
Example Name
>>> record.company_id.name
Company Name
>>> record.name = "Bob"
>>> field = "name"
>>> record[field]
Bob
```

I am confused by the line `record.company_id.name`. It seems safe to assume that 'record' is the table name. I would guess that 'company_id' is a column name in the 'record' table. But then if that is true, why is 'name' appended to 'company_id' with the dot operator? This is where I am confused.

I understand the code that accesses the "name" field in the "record" table like this: `record.name`. However, the field access with three dots `record.company_id.name` does not seem logical. Seems like this is trying to access a field of a field?

Thanks for reading this. Please let me know how I can improve.

Comment: in the case of ```record.company_id.name```

company_id is a many2one link to another table from record

Comment: You also need to recognize that `record` is a variable, not exactly the table name. It is likely an instance (recordset) of an Odoo model/object. For example, `record` might contain `res.partner(23,)` which would basically be an ORM representation of a single row from the `res_partner` table.